# Despite having a delay my function gets executed too quickly

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code:

```
 let playableCards = self.allPlayableCardsViews[0].allSubviews.flatMap { $0 as? UIButton }
var counter: Double = 0
   for card in playableCards{

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: TimeInterval(counter), options: .init(rawValue: 0), animations: {
            card.alpha = 1.0
            print("hello")

        }, completion: nil)
        counter += (3.7/Double(16))
    }
```

Normally in the print line there is a function. This function gets called the amount of loops which of course is good. However I want to add the same delay that is having my card to fade in. Now my function gets called without the delay, causing 16 functions to execute at the exact same time, which is I think weird because I clearly added a delay. I do not want to use completion since the function needs to be executed at the exact same time as the card fades in. How can it be that the card is fading in one after another and the function(print in this example) gets called without delays?

I now see in my debug session 16 times "hello" while the cards are still fading in.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The animation is delayed, but the block can be called at any time to figure out what properties are being animated -- these don't need to be at the same time.

Use a timer to call your function at the same time as the animation will go off.  If you want it to be triggered by the animation actually happening, you may be able to use key-value observing (KVO) on the `card.alpha` property.